# Date and number of guests validation in booking application with Django

Tags: python, validation, django-forms

The app I am working on is table booking. I am using django.
I am aiming to add some custom form validation to my django model form. I am using the def clean method but when manually testing the form, no error message is coming.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Reservation, Table
from datetime import datetime
import arrow
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
date = forms.DateField(input_formats=\['%d/%m/%Y'\])  # Set the input format

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ReservationForm, self).clean()
    date = cleaned_data.get('date')
    number_of_guests = cleaned_data.get('number_of_guests')

    # Check if the date is in the correct format: dd/mm/yyyy
    try:
        datetime.strptime(str(date), '%Y-%m-%d')
    except ValueError:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid date format. Please use the format DD/MM/YYYY.')

    # Check if the date is in the past
    if date and arrow.utcnow().datetime < date:
        raise forms.ValidationError('You can’t book a table in the past')
    
    #Check if number_of_guests are not None and not small or equal to null
    if number_of_guests is not None and number_of_guests <= 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Number of guests must be greater than 0.')

    return cleaned_data

class Meta:
    model = Reservation
    fields = ('date', 'time', 'number_of_guests', 'number_of_child_seats', 'comment')`
```

What I tried to solve the issue:

I tried to implement the logic in my views file but that didn't work either.
I ran my code through a python code validator, no errors in the syntax found.
I double checked the form_valid function in my views.py file but couldn't find a reason for it not to work.

I also checked the console when sending false data to the database and interestingly I am getting the following error: content-script.js:1  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')

Which is interesting because I don't have an self-coded javascript there. content-script.js seems to be something generated through Django.

This is my class-based view for the creation of my reservation.

```
class CreateReservation(CreateView):
model = Reservation
template_name = "tablebooking/create_booking.html"
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
form_class = ReservationForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    data = form.cleaned_data
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    tables = Table.objects.filter(number_of_seats__gte=form.instance.number_of_guests)
    if tables.exists():
            form.instance.table = tables.first()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

And this is my model:

```
class Reservation (models.Model):  
table = models.ForeignKey(Table, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)  
date = models.DateField()  
time = models.TimeField()  
number_of_guests = models.PositiveIntegerField()  
number_of_child_seats = models.PositiveIntegerField()  
comment = models.TextField(blank=True)  
is_waitlisted = models.BooleanField(default=False)\`
```

Would appreciate help. Thanks in advance!